# Deviation on the Diffraction Pattern when not perpendicular

Tags: optics, interference, diffraction

Due to Babinet principle, Diffraction pattern of an opaque .... ( you all know ). here my opaque is my wire.

So, I know that if I change the angle between beam and wire ( I mean if I don't aim the laser perpendicular to wire and aim it with angle 60 for example ) I'll see the same diffraction pattern. but there will be a difference. 
When we aim the laser not perpendicular, depending on the angle we've aimed, the whole diffraction pattern will be deviated ( Picture below ) and Diffraction pattern won't be on a straight line anymore.
[image]

[image]

My question is why this happens ( deviation of diffraction pattern ) ?

Comment: Looks more like reflection than a diffraction pattern.

Comment: No, I've taken a picture form this more clear that I'll add to the question

Comment: I am still pretty sure the non-straightness is due to reflection. The intensity is way to high for diffraction. There might be an interference pattern in the reflected light (this where not too surprising, but I would not be sure, based on the picture).